# Render secure content inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, xmlhttprequest

I want to display the PDF document inside `iframe` element (just set `src` attribute an browser will use **native PDF viewer** in this case).

To access the document I have to set `Authentication` header with `base64(username:password)`. But I have no idea how to do that with `iframe`. Also I can get PDF binary data using XHR but I cannot figure out how to display it in the page.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting the header, can you just access the document with username and password in the url?

```
https://username:password@www.example.com/path
```

Comment: Seems like this is unstable solution. Chrome displays PDF's binary data as plain text. Chrome Cannary and Firefox tries to download the file :(

Comment: Probably it depends on document headers. I will check if this solution is crossbrowser and accept your answer later. Thank for your help!